# How do you find the "rank" of a school or program?

Tags: graduate-school, education, ranking

I am preparing to pursue higher education and I was reading articles about schools. In one of the articles it was mentioned that the author attended a "high teens" ranked school. There was no mention of who ranked this school, how it was ranked, or why. I assume the idea was that I should be impressed by the implication that his school was ranked between 19-16 (my scale for "high" teens).

Who is ranking these schools and what does this number mean? How do I find out my schools ranking?

Comment: Lots of places do rankings.  See e.g. http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1178/19607

Comment: This question excellently summarizes how rankings work: The reader of a mentioned ranking is unsure about the source of a ranking and about the concrete meaning of the score, but they are left with a vague feeling that they should probably be impressed by the ranking nonetheless ;)

Comment: As a tangential comment, I am not sure whether  I would interpret "high teens" to mean "11-15" in this context or "16-19"; both seem equally likely (and equally ambiguous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can rank schools.

Some rankings are more popular than others (e.g., [US News](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges)) and some may do so based on particular metrics but there is no de facto ranking system in the world.

What they *actually* mean is up for interpretation, and unless they provide the complete methodology then it is rather difficult to find meaning in them at all.

Comment: That answers that. I assumed there was a central ranking authority or government authority who provides a blessing of sort for programs. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ILikeTurtles I don't doubt that governments and communities have their own accepted ranking systems, but nothing is globally accepted and they would still have the same faults.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/)